# Given a, b, c and alpha find x

Tags: math, image-processing, geometry-surface, triangular

I was doing image processing to determine the distance between two points in a picture. it involves a fair amount of geometry. One of the problems which I tried to solve using basic geometry but failed to arrive at a solution is the following. I have transformed the question into mathematical terms so that a wider audience could answer it.

[image: fig]

The sides a, b, c, and the angle alpha are given. The length x is to be found
Using sine and cosine laws I`ve found:
Using Cosine Law and, 
Using Sine Law

[image: fig2]

where beta is the angle opposite the side b

Comment: Hi, can you give at least one example set of values in order to test the results? There isn't a simple formula here, and the answer will require some level of programming a numeric solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a trivial problem, and maybe it should have been asked [Math.SE](http://math.stackexchange.com).

But here is my take:

[image: fig]

Considering the triangle `abx`

```
b^2 = x^2 + a^2 - 2*a*x*cos(β)        #1
```

And the triangle `a1cx`

```
c^2 = x^2 + a1^2 -2*a1*x*cos(β)       #2
sin(α)/α1 = sin(β)/c                  #3
```

Three non-linear equations to be solved for `x`, `a1` and `β`.

Subtract `#2` from `#1` to eliminate `x^2` (with some simplifications)

```
b^2 - c^2  = -2*x *(a-a1)*cos(β)+a^2 -a1^2        #4
```

use `#3` to eliminate `β` in terms of `a1` in `#4`

```
b^2 - c^2 = -2*x*(a-a1)*sqrt(1 - c^2/a1^2*sin(α)^2)+a^2-a1^2  #5
```

Now subtract `(a/a1)*#2` from `#1` to eliminate `a1^2`

```
b^2 - a*c^2/a1 = -(a-a1)*(x^2-a*a1)/a1            #6
```

Equations `#5` and `#6` are two non-linear equations to be solved for `x` and `a1`.

From `#5` we have `x` in terms of `a1` with

```
x = a1*(a^2-a1^2-b^2+c^2)/(2*(a-a1)*sqrt(a1^2-c^2*sin(α)^2))    #7
```

Unfortunately using the above in `#6` results in a *sixth order polynomial* to be solved for `a1`.

It can only be solved numerically at this point. **If `a1` is found, then `#7` also gives us `x`.**

```
0 = 4*a^2*c^2*g^2
+ a1*(4*a*g^2*(a^2-b^2-c^2))
+ a1^2*(a^4-2a^2(b^2+c^2+4g^2)+b^4+2b^2(2g^2-c^2)+c^4)
+ a1^3*(-4a(a^2-b^2-c^2-g^2))
+ a1^4*(2(3a^2-b^2-c^2))
+ a1^5*(-4*a)
+ a1^6
```

where `g = c*sin(α)`

Comment: But then there will be 6 different solutions right? Geometrically, I see a unique solution.

Comment: There will be a number of invalid solutions (complex numbers, or negative numbers) and fro the remaining one there will be multiple configurations possible. Like the `c` distance outside of the main triangle. Here is the part where if I had real numbers to work with I could further develop the algorithm based on valid solution branches.